# Replace Current fragment with another fragment from within the Current fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have an activity named as

```
MainActivity
```

i have added a fragment "`BenefitFragment`" in container `R.id.mainContainer`.

In BenefitFragment layout i have another container `R.id.benefitContainer`. I am adding a nested fragment as

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.benefitContainer, new ConfirmPinFragment())
                        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.do_nothing)
                        .addToBackStack("benefit")
                        .commit();
```

In my `ConfirmPinFragment` after some processing i want to remove this ConfirmPinFragment and replace it with another Fragment let's say `TestFragment` and TestFragment can replace itself with another fragment and so on.

Here is what i tried in `ConfirmPinFragment`

```
CorporateFragment fragment = new CorporateFragment();
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .addToBackStack("benefit")
                                .hide(ConfirmPinFragment.this)
                                .add(android.R.id.content, fragment)
                                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.do_nothing)
                        .commit();
```

However i am getting error `android.R.id.content not found`. I want to replace the fragment from inside it and replace with another fragment, how will i do it.

Comment: android.R.id.content to R.id.content

Comment: First thing first `android.R.id.content` is for entire screen. What don't you get the view of `R.id.benefitContainer` from `parenFragment` and pass its id as a container id instead of `android.R.id.content`

Comment: `BenefitFragment` will be your `parentFragment` here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see `BenefitFragment` will be your parent `Fragment` for both `ConfirmPinFragment` and `CorporateFragment`.

So pass `R.id.benefitContainer` as a container of your fragment in which your fragment to be replaced. But you need to resolve that id first. to do so you need to use `getParentFragment()`.

Try to write this in your `ConfirmPinFragment`.

```
Fragment mF = getParentFragment();
// double check
if (mF instanceof  BenefitFragment) {
     getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(((BenefitFragment)getParentFragment()).getView().findViewById(R.id.benefitContainer).getId()
                            , new CorporateFragment())
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.do_nothing)
                    .addToBackStack("benefit")
                    .commit();
}
```

Comment: u are passing .add(View, fragment)? no such method

Comment: instead of that i have done getParentFragment.getChildmanager and now its working

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, BenefitFragment is your parent fragment and you added ConfirmPinFragment successfully as it's child fragment. Now other fragments let's say TestFragment Or CorporateFragment etc are child fragment of BenefitFragment same as of ConfirmPinFragment. So you have to do same as you had done with ConfirmPinFragment adding code. Just replace **add** method with the **replace**.

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.benefitContainer, new CorporateFragment())
                        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.do_nothing)
                        .addToBackStack("ConfirmPin")
                        .commit();
```

And your layout container for all child fragment will be `R.id.benefitContainer`

Comment: No view found for id 0x7f0d0129 (apppackage:id/benefitContainer) for fragment CorporateFragment

Comment: How you did it can you show your code and please also add xml layout for benefitContainer?

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, tag).addToBackStack(tag).commit();


//"content_frame" is the name of your view where the Fragment will be shown and //"fragment" is the name of your Fragment
```

the above code will replace your Fragment